# como quitar caracteres de un texto?

Tags: html, c#

```
@Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control grayText", @autocomplete = "off", @id = "UserNameTB", @required = "true", @Value = @User.Identity.Name } })
```

tengo este codigo que me trae el usuario de windows a mi pagina web pero el usuario inicia con 7 letras que quiero quitarlas como puedo hacer esto ?  @User.Identity.Name aqui esta alojado los usarios que todos traen esas mismas 7 letras.

Edito: Probé con esta otra opción:

```
Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { class = "form-control grayText", autocomplete = "off", id = "UserNameTB".Replace('UserName', string.Empty), required = "true", Value = User.Identity.Name } })
```

Pero obtengo

> Error CS1012 Demasiados caracteres en literal de carácter

Comment: Yo aprovecharía para revisar las preguntas anteriores que has hecho porque si alguien históricamente ignora lo que el resto de la comunidad le sugiere, seguro es menos probable que la gente se interese por responder. Dicho esto, la respuesta a esta pregunta parece buena; si te sirve, no olvides marcarla como aceptada

Comment: ya resolvi las ateriores preguntas ? ahhora tengo esta !

Comment: Claro, pero un mod te pidió borrar una no respuesta y ahí sigue. No has añádido tu propia respuesta si es que ya las resolviste. Y por lo que parece, no has pasado por los enlaces que te sugirieron para entender mejor el sitio y hacer que tus preguntas reciban respuesta más rápido.

Comment: Una vez más: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Que hayas resuelto las anteriores preguntas no significa que las dejes sin editar ni responder: las preguntas/respuestas aquí deben ser útil _para todos_, no solo para el autor de la pregunta. Ten en cuenta que esto no es un foro.

Comment: No vandalices la pregunta. Quitar la pregunta inicial hace que sea imposible que alguien te dé una respuesta si se pierde la pista del problema inicial. Te acabo de ayudar con la edición. Déjate guiar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar Replace()

Por ejemplo:

```
@id = "UserNameTB".Replace('UserName', ''));
```

o

```
@id = "UserNameTB".Replace('UserName', string.Empty));
```

Comment: Al ingresar cualquiera de las dos opciones me sale un error que dice "Error CS1012 Demasiados caracteres en literal de carácter " la estoy insertando 
en esta misma linea que pena soy nueva en esto no es que conozca mucho la verdad
asi quedo el codigo y presenta el error.

Comment: Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { class = "form-control grayText", autocomplete = "off", id = "UserNameTB".Replace('UserName', string.Empty), required = "true", Value = User.Identity.Name } })

Comment: @SandraMilenaLozanoRojas Acá abajo el código es ilegible. Si hay cosas que añadir, por favor ve a editar la pregunta y añade todas las aclaraciones que necesites. Ejemplo: Bajo la pregunta original, puedes añadir "Edicion: probé xxx código y la salida fue yyy"

Comment: @SandraMilenaLozanoRojas la mejor idea es que proceses los caracteres del usuario de manera separada. 
Guarda el nombre de usuario en una variable string.
Y procésala con el Replace(), después de eso, agrégala en la linea del http

Comment: es que el usuario lo debe traer del logeo de windows,